# What is the relation between $m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ and $m^*(A+B)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A, B$ be nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $m^*$ be the Lebesgue outer measure (and $m$ the Lebesgue measure). Define $A+B = \{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$. What can we say about the relation between $m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ and $m^*(A+B)$?

Some remarks/progress:

- There certainly exist sets whose sum of the measures is measure of sum, for example let $A = B = (0, 1)$, then $A+B = (0, 2)$ and $m^*(A)+m^*(B) = m^*(A+B) = 2$. Additionally, whenever $A$ or $B$ have infinite measure, the case of equality always holds by the following observation (assuming wlog $A$ has infinite measure and $b\in B$): $$m^*(A + B)\geq m^*(A+b) = m^*(A) = \infty = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$$
- There also exist sets whose sum of measures is strictly less than the measure of the sum. If $A = [0, 1]$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}$, then $A + B = \mathbb{R}$. So we get $$m^*(A) + m^*(B) = 1$$ and $$m^*(A+B) = \infty > m^*(A) + m^*(B).$$
- (If $A = (0, 1)$ and $B = \emptyset$, then we get $m^*(A) + m^*(B) = 1$, and $m^*(A+B) = 0$. This certainly shows an example of $A$ and $B$ where $m^*(A)+m^*(B) > m^*(A+B)$ but it's special and involves the unique property of empty sets. That's why I want $A$ and $B$ to be *nonempty*.)

So the question amounts to showing: in general or for nonempty Lebesgue measurable sets $A$ and $B$, is it true that $m^*(A)+m^*(B)\leq m^*(A+B)$?

---

I don't think there's a lot to work with when talking about sums of sets, but here'as a failed attempt.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are measurable so that we can use additivity. Let $b\in B$, then we get $$\begin{align}
m(A+B) &= m(A+b\cup B\backslash\{b\})\\
&= m((A+b)\cup(A+B\backslash\{b\})\backslash(A+b))\\
&= m(A+b) + m((A+B\backslash\{b\})\backslash(A+b))\\
&= m(A) + m((A+B\backslash\{b\})\backslash(A+b)),
\end{align}$$
so I've basically shifted responsibility to proving $m((A+B\backslash\{b\})\backslash(A+b))\geq m(B)$. However, this doesn't even hold if $A = B = \mathbb{R}$. So this line of proof doesn't work. Maybe it will if $A$ and $B$ have finite measure.

Comment: You might be interested in the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem

Comment: @PhoemueX that's pretty interesting, thanks for the reference.